# How to fetch data from external site to own site

Tags: php, jquery

I want to fetch data from live stock market to my web site. By using php and jQuery.

Comment: Please remove the extra "checking out the markup language" text from your question. Also please show what you have already tried and where you are having problems.

Answer (score 0):

Has the source got an API you can work with to fetch the data? If so read their docs and implement it.

If not you could possibly do a Curl request and parse the data you need if your allowed.

More importantly you need to be more specific with your question if you want to get good answers, if any at all :-).

Comment: ok for example pls check this site http://merolagani.com/LatestMarket.aspx . I want this data to fetech to my website. pls give the code to fetech data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a web **service** that offers a stock market feed in the form of JSON or XML, so that your computer would be able to parse it. Not a website. Most of those feeds are paid - especially those that are close to real-time.

Then, once you have such a feed, you should be able to access it via your browser - just by typing in the URL. For example, http://www.quotewebsite.com/symbol=MSFT

This will help you understand what your server side script is supposed to do. Then, in your PHP script (PHP is a server-side programming language), issue a CURL request to download that specific page into your website's database (ex. MySQL). This will allow you to have historical data inside your own system. Then you get to render that data back to your own customers by querying your own database.